# Child DIV exceeding Parent DIV

Tags: css, html, height, parent

If I place Content DIV (100% height) after Header, if even exceeds the Parent DIVs (SuperContainer DIV and Wrapper with an 100% height).

What I am trying to achieve is, i want the content div to be 100% (means, i want it to be stretched to the end of the page), and if the text inside it overflows or exceeds, i want the parent divs to extend along accordingly.

Please let me know the solution for this. Below is the code... Please help. Thanks.

CSS:

```
    * {
    margin: 0;
    }
```

```
html, body {
height:100%;
}

#wrapper {
width: 75%;
background-color:#09F;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
height:100%;
}

#super_container{
height:100%;
width: 50%;
background-color:#FF0;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

#content_container{
width: 50%;
background-color:#F00;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
height:100%;
}

#header{
height:250px;
}
</pre>
```

HTML:
    
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="super_container">
            <div id="header">
                Header
            </div>
            <div id="content_container">
                Testing
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

Comment: This question is very vague right now, but I want to give you an opportunity to edit it and make it clearer since I believe there may be a legitimate problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't it? header is 250px height and content_container is 100% so 100% + 250px is greater than 100%.

How to fix it depends on a lot of factors.

If you want content to shrink as header grows you need `display:table` on super_container and `display:table-row` on header and content (in short, you need a table).

Other solutions invlove pulling the content up under the header (using absolute positioning on the header and suitable spacing at the top of content). There are also tricks with negative margins.

I suggest you look for a layout that does what you want and base your layout of that.

Comment: Actually i am concerned with Content DIV. I want the content div to be 100% but do not want it to exceed parent divs. Also if content overflows, i would like parent divs to increase accordingly. That is what i want to achieve.

Comment: It exceeds the parent divs because `height` is a fixed quantity. It can never be greater than or less than its value (100% in this case). It sounds like what you actually want is `min-height:100%` on your containers. That means they'll fill 100% of the space (the window in your example) but if they are forced beyond 100% by child elements then they'll happily expand.

Answer (score 0):

Check for **min-width** being applied to the child element